# Why is it slow to scroll up/down from this website using chrome?

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome

I was visiting several websites and found below one. I was actually surprised that website with few images is very slow to scroll up/down with chrome (Version 39.0.2171.95).

With firefox, there is initial lag, but it seems to work somewhat fine after few up and downs.

With IE, I was surprisingly able to scroll up and down without any kind of lag.

http://www.northwestautosalon.com/services/exterior-detailing/paintless-dent-repair/

Is there something that chrome is not good at that makes this website slow?

Comment: Using chrome profiling tools one can easily detect the scrolling bottleneck.

Answer (score 1):

```
#page-title {
width: 100%;
height: 769px;
position: relative;
z-index: 1;
margin-top: -197px;
**box-shadow: inset 0 -65px 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .5), inset 0 265px 265px -184px;**
}
```

This enormous box shadow creates a lagging. Perhaps you've tried it on the IE <9, which doesn't support border-shadow property.